# Detecting vehicle at traffic light using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have write a code to detect vehicle between two picture.first image is the reference image.the second image is the capture image.
the problem is if i want to use live video to detect the vehicle,what code should i add to my code?
i want to use live webcam to detect the vehicle.

this my code:

```
display('Initiating matching...');
display('Calibrating procedures...');
display('... ... ...');
k=imread ('DSC00018.jpg');
p=imread ('DSC00019.jpg');
[x,y,z] = size(k);
if(z==1)
;
else

 k = rgb2gray(k);
  figure
  imshow(k)

  end

  [x,y,z] = size(p);
   if(z==1)
   ;
  else
  p = rgb2gray(p);
   figure
  imshow(p)

   end    


   %applying edge detection on first picture

   %in the picture.
   k1=imresize(k,[300 300]);
  edge_det_k = edge(k1,'sobel');


   %%applying edge detection on second picture

    %in the picture.
   p1=imresize(p,[300 300]);
   edge_det_p = edge(p1,'sobel');



   %definition of different variables to be used in the code below


    %output variable if pictures have been matched.
    OUTPUT_MESSAGE = ' RED for 90 seconds ';
    OUTPUT_MESSAGE2 = ' GREEN for 20 seconds ';
    OUTPUT_MESSAGE3 = ' GREEN for 30 seconds ';
     OUTPUT_MESSAGE4 = ' GREEN for 60 seconds ';
     OUTPUT_MESSAGE5 = ' GREEN for 90 seconds ';
     %initialization of different variables used


     matched_data = 0;
     white_points = 0;
     black_points = 0;
     x=0;
     y=0;
     l=0;
     m=0;


     %for loop used for detecting black and white points in the picture.
      for a = 1:1:300
      for b = 1:1:300
      if(edge_det_k(a,b)==1)
                white_points = white_points+1;
             else
          black_points = black_points+1;
         end
        end
       end
      display('matching...');
      %for loop comparing the white (edge points) in the two pictures
      for i = 1:1:300
               for j = 1:1:300
        if(edge_det_k(i,j)==1)&(edge_det_p(i,j)==1)
         matched_data = matched_data+1;
       else

         ;
             end
          end
       end

        %calculating percentage matching.
        total_data = white_points;
        total_matched_percentage = (matched_data/total_data)*100;
        %handles.pp=total_matched_percentage;
        %guidata(hObject,handles);

         %outputting the result of the system.
         if total_matched_percentage > 90       %can add flexability at                        this point by reducing the amount of matching.


total_matched_percentage
OUTPUT_MESSAGE

elseif total_matched_percentage <= 90 & total_matched_percentage > 70
 total_matched_percentage
 OUTPUT_MESSAGE2
display(OUTPUT_MESSAGE2);



 elseif total_matched_percentage <= 70 & total_matched_percentage > 50
 total_matched_percentage
 OUTPUT_MESSAGE3
 display(OUTPUT_MESSAGE3);

  elseif total_matched_percentage <= 50 & total_matched_percentage > 10
   total_matched_percentage
 OUTPUT_MESSAGE4
 display(OUTPUT_MESSAGE4);


  else
      total_matched_percentage
       OUTPUT_MESSAGE5
       display(OUTPUT_MESSAGE5);

    end
```

Comment: If you want to run this code on a live video, then wrap your code in a function and call it on every (n-th) frame of your video. This is the most naive way. Once you achieve satisfactory accuracy in that, you can maybe look for tracking.

Comment: Can you provide a sample video?